# eslint not formatting index.ts on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

In vscode settings I have:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true,
}
"eslint.enable": true,
"eslint.validate": [
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact",
],
```

When saving something.ts with this:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';

import { transactionsValueProps } from './interface';
import { TransactionsContext } from './TransactionsContext';
```

It moves `import { TransactionsContext } from './TransactionsContext';` above `import { transactionsValueProps } from './interface';`. Not sure why because it's not alphabetically correct, but if that's the default of eslint, so be it.

However, when I save `index.ts` with this:

```
export * from './interface';
export * from './TransactionsContext';
export * from './useTransactionsContext';
```

It doesn't move things around. In fact, I can sort it as I wish, and nothing will get sorted.

How come? Am I missing something in vscode settings??